# Merge data table into dataset and save changes back to data source

Tags: c#

First c# project and I need to pull records off a remote SQL Server into a localDB instance. Reading so many docs I'm about brain dead. Source is a npsql datasource. Target is localdb instance I built the local table with the same schema. I don't think `SqlBulkCopy` is the right solution here so I'm trying to bring over changes and adds. While I get no errors in the code the localdb instance is not updated.

```
DataTable custMsrDT = this.MeasureDB.getMsrCustomerDT();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LocalDB.connStringLocalDB))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, crm_customer_id, jb_customer_id, fname, lname, phone, alt_phone, email, street_address, unit_number, neighborhood, city, state, zip, county FROM dbo.customer;", connection);

    DataSet localDS = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(localDS, "customer");
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

    localDS.Tables["customer"].RowChanged += new System.Data.DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);

    localDS.Tables["customer"].Merge(custMsrDT, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);

    da.Update(localDS, "customer");
}
```

Comment: `im trying to bring over changes and adds` it sounds like you are trying to synch them, as opposed to import from one to another?

Comment: yeah.. i seen something about sync framework.  im close to giving that a read.

Comment: That was a question.  I have a deleted answer that shows how to copy, but then I saw that phrase.  `i need to pull records` isnt the same as hinted at with the later phrase.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.  using the table.merge function was not the answer.  it comes down to understanding how the row state is set.  in the original the rowstate was always "unchanged" thus the datatable.update was not doing anything.  using the [load function on the table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx) was the correct approach.

```
    DataTable custMsrDT = this.MeasureDB.getMsrCustomerDT();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(LocalDB.connStringLocalDB))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, crm_customer_id, jb_customer_id, fname, lname, phone, alt_phone, email, street_address, unit_number, neighborhood, city, state, zip, county FROM dbo.customer;", connection);

        DataSet localDS = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(localDS, "customer");

        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

        localDS.Tables["customer"].RowChanged += new System.Data.DataRowChangeEventHandler(Row_Changed);


        //localDS.Tables["customer"].Merge(custMsrDT, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);


        using (DataTableReader changeReader = new DataTableReader(custMsrDT))
        {

            localDS.Tables["customer"].Load(changeReader, LoadOption.Upsert);

        }

        PrintColumns(localDS.Tables["customer"]);

        DisplayRowState(localDS.Tables["customer"]);

        da.Update(localDS, "customer")
```